# illegal start of type: Often this message means that you are missing a { BEFORE this line

Tags: java, arrays

Could anyone help me out with this error?
I couldn't rectify this code.
I can't understand the error.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class findMax{
    public static int findMax(int[] arr){
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < value.length; i++){
            if (value[i] > max){
                max = value[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int value[];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        value = in.nextInt();
        findMax(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't assign an `int` to an `int[]` like that. Also, you need to check the first index in the array (which is `0`, not `1`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment,
But still the error rises.

Comment: Can you comment below the error-free code of mine?

Answer (score 1):

In the function `findMax`, you need to be consistent with your array variable name (you're currently passing `int[] arr` but accessing `value`). Also, you don't want to default `max` to `0` (you could use `arr[0]`). Something like,

```
public static int findMax(int[] arr) {
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Next, you need to *instantiate* and *assign* values into your array (and do something with the result of `findMax` as is the result isn't used). There are a few ways to do that. One might be,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] value = new int[] { in.nextInt() };
    int max = findMax(value);
    System.out.printf("The max value in %s is %d.%n", Arrays.toString(value), max);
}
```

*Alternatively*, you could create the array like

```
int[] value = new int[1];
value[0] = in.nextInt();
```

**Also**, you *could* eliminate the `if` if you use `Math.max(int, int)` in `findMax` like

```
public static int findMax(int[] arr) {
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, arr[i]);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: You must be omitting something from your question, because I successfully ran this code.

Comment: Find the maximum value in an array. For example:
findMax({1,2,3,2,5,2,3}) => 5
findMax({5,5,5}) => 5
findMax({-1, -2, -3}) => -1


This is my question

Comment: Call the code I posted with `int max = findMax(new int[] {1,2,3,2,5,2,3});`

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate, cause i can't get you!

Comment: Which part do you not understand, the inline syntax for a Java `int[]` is `new int[] {1,2,3}` not `{1,2,3}` (there is syntactic sugar for `int[] a = {1,2,3};` but that doesn't work inline to a function call).

Answer (score -1):

```
  Try this 
 public static int findMax(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
            int max = arr.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++){
                if (arr.get(i) > max){
                    max = arr.get(i);
                }
            }
            return max;
        }   
        public static void main(String[] args){;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            ArrayList<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            System.out.print("Enter integers please ");
            System.out.println("(EOF or non-integer to terminate): ");

            while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                value.add(in.nextInt());
            }

            System.out.println(findMax(value));
        }
```

Comment: What is the `max` of `Arrays.asList(-1,-2,-3)`?

Comment: I've tried your code above,
But the error sustains.

Comment: why this answer was not useful? may i know?

Comment: please copy error logs and also show how you are calling my code

Comment: Please write comments why this answer was not useful?

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stack{ public static int findMax(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++){
        if (arr.get(i) > max){
            max = arr.get(i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}   
public static void main(String[] args){;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.print("Enter integers please ");
    System.out.println("(EOF or non-integer to terminate): ");

    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
        value.add(in.nextInt());
    }

    System.out.println(findMax(value));
}}
```

Comment: I've pasted the code exactly as you wrote,
I don't know why the error pops up again and again!

Comment: What is the error? Are you sure the file name  is equal to the class name?which is Stack?

Comment: This is an online Compiler called Cloud Coder

Comment: I've tried the code  here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php  Unfortunately I I cannot access your provided online Compiler